# Updating Subdocument Array in PHP Mongo

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am trying to update subdocument array in PHP Mongo

```
$result = $collection->updateMany(
    [
        '_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('61613dcd437b996bc227ffe2'),
        'messages.type' => 'test'
    ],
    ['$set' => ['messages.$[m].direction' => '999']],
    [
      'multi' => true,
      'arrayFilters' => [['m.type'=> 'test']]
    ]

);
```

####Update . My array is

[{"_id":{"$oid":"6163f2c9fc197a54f03ca8c8"},"id":7,},"messages":{"1":{"type":"1","time":"19.04.2020 09:14:42","message":"This is testmsg"}},"ssg":"ruther"}]

Also, How Can I update whole sub-document with indexes1,2,3.. so on ?

Comment: Why do you store numeric values as string? And why do you store `Date` values as string? Use proper [data types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/), then your query will work.

Comment: For Date use `new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($value)`, see https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$[]` and `arrayFilters`

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("61603458c08ad41af13bf352"),
  "messages.type": "05.04.2020 03:27:23"
},
{
  $set: {
    "messages.$[m].direction": "999"
  }
},
{
  multi: true,
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "m.type": "05.04.2020 03:27:23"
    }
  ]
})
```

**Update**

If you want to replace that single Message array with the new one

```
$set: {
    "messages.$[m]": {
      "type": "02.06.2020 19:27:23",
      "message": "This is a 3 Msg",
      "direction": "0"
    }
  }
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jvRYdkm7NeP)

Comment: But it is imp to use _id with messages.type. Is it ok, if I combine with _id ?

Comment: Also, How Can I update whole sub-document ? i.e. I want to replace that single Message array with the new one (Instead of replace single type column)

Comment: Sure you can, I update my answer.

Comment: Hi, @YuTing. Your query working.But can you plz help. how I handle sub document array "messages":{"1":{"type":"notes","time":"19.04.2020 09:14:42","message":"fakemsg","direction":"0"}}

Comment: How Can I update whole sub-document with indexes1,2,3.. so on.Plz check my question